# Animating SVG path with CSS in IE11

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

### THE BACKGROUND

I'm working on a game in the style of Symon, where a user has to click elements in the right order as the computer generates a random sequence.

The elements are made out of SVG paths.

I wish to have a PENDING status on the game, where one of the elements is flashing repeatedly to draw user interaction

I'm working on IE11

### THE ISSUE

I can't seem to get the Paths to animate a flashing color. I'm not very experienced with css animation but it seems like I've done everything right, and I've used many different examples to write this bit of code. It's ignoring the class `pending` that is meant to infinitely animate the path element.

```
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0% {
        fill: black;
    }
    100% {
        fill: #ff7420;
    }
}

@keyframes flash {
    0% {
        fill: black;
    }
    100% {
        fill: #ff7420;
    }
}

.game_tri.pending path {
    transform:translatey(-100px);
    animation-name: flash;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-name: flash;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
}
```

Full code on:

JSFIDDLE **https://jsfiddle.net/tomshanan/oushonob/10/**

### BONUS QUESTION

I  would love to know if anyone can tell why the game stops working once I remove `active` from the `game_tri` classes on line 9.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".game_tri").attr("class", "game_tri active pending");

        reset_game();
    });
```

When you press the Next Round button, this should reinsert that class anyway,  but the game does not respond if that class is removed initially. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE prior to [IE Edge](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/csstransitionsanimationsforsvgelements/) does not support CSS animations applied to SVG elements.

Comment: Is there a different way to animate the SVG element in the same fashion?

Comment: update the attributes using javascript and setTimeout or use SMIL and [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/)